# Validate if command was successfull in a batch file or revert back all settings

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript, server

Please check my batch file command as I need to dis-join computer from old domain and join it to a new one.

Sometimes computer succeeded to dis-join the computer but fails to add it in a new domain so this computer will be out of domain. I need to add command to validate if the computer is successfully joined to the new domain otherwise revert it back to the old domain.

```batch
@echo off
netdom.exe remove %computername% /domain:MyOlddomain.local /UserD:Myusername /PasswordD:Mypassword
Ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 >nul
netdom.exe join %computername% /domain:MyNewDomain /UserD:Myusername /PasswordD:Mypassword
Ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 >nul
shutdown -t 5 -r -f
```

Comment: What does the question have to do with PowerShell or VBScript? Did you try checing the errorlevel after the remove operation?

Answer (score 0):

The best way about it is to use a IF statement.

The basic structure of a IF statement is as follows.

```
IF EXIST "%1" (
    echo "it's here!"
) ELSE (
    echo "it isn't here!"
)
```

Going about it like this will allow you to revert when needed.
[More in depth reading!](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490920.aspx)

Comment: Please elaborate how the OP should use an `if` statement to validate whether or not a domain join failed.